# Tutorial for emp package

Tags: metapost

I really like the idea of the [emp](http://ctan.org/pkg/emp) package - you write your MetaPost sources directly in LaTeX source. However, I can't make this package work. I read the official readme, but to no avail. Some of my problems:

- Should every `emp` command go inside an `empfile` environment?
- Should I have one big `empfile` environment that contains all of my TeX source? (If yes, then it's terribly ugly!)
- Why am I mixing TeX code and MetaPost code inside `emp*` environments?
- Do I have to put `emp` environment inside a `figure` environment?
- Can I have multiple unnamed `empfile` environments?

In other words: How does this thing work?

Comment: Have you read the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/emp/empman.pdf)? It contains examples.

Comment: @Gonzalo: I did, but they are not explanatory enough for me - all of the commands are explained without showing the full TeX source, or for example the `empfile` environment spans for the whole document (which is very short).

Comment: I suggest you to look also at the more recent packages **mpgraphics** and **gmp** (I'm the author of the latter).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to look also at the more recent packages **mpgraphics** and **gmp** (I'm the author of the latter), as **emp** looks not to have been maintained for a long time.

Both package do what **emp** is able to do, and much more.